# How can catkin find ROS libraries in non-standard locations?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually the complete question would be: How can catkin find ROS libraries in non-standard locations, or is it ok **not** to write a library for Python in `catkin_package(...)`?

I wrote a library in C++ for Python to wrap a C++ class. For it to be usable in Python I needed to change the default location. Extract of `CMakeLists.txt` in package `crossing_detector`:

> set_target_properties(crossing_detector_wrapper_cpp PROPERTIES

> PREFIX ""

> LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DESTINATION})

This work well in the sense that I can use it in Python with

> from crossing_detector.crossing_detector_wrapper_cpp import CrossingDetectorWrapper

The problem comes when I want to compile separately (`catkin_make_isolated` or `catkin build`) another package that depends on `crossing_detector`, catkin complains about a missing library:

> Project 'dataset_analyzer' tried to find library 'crossing_detector_wrapper_cpp'.  The library is neither a target nor
> built/installed properly
> The library is not even needed there.

The problem doesn't occur when compiling both packages together (`catkin_make`).

See also: https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/128

I'm thinking of solving the problem by removing the library from `catkin_package(...)`. Is this ok to do so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201036/how-can-catkin-find-ros-libraries-in-non-standard-locations?/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The strategy proposed by William works well with `catkin_make_isolated` and `catkin build`, where multiple CMake projects exist, and the dependency is built before it is required. It however breaks under `catkin_make`, where there is a single CMake project and the dependency has not yet been built when it is required (hence `find_library` fails). For completeness, I have put together a a slightly modified version that is compatible with both single- and multi-CMake projects:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
catkin_package(
  ...
  LIBRARIES # NOTE: Not specified here, but in extras file
  CFG_EXTRAS foo-extras.cmake
)
```

**foo-extras.cmake.in**

```
find_library(@PROJECT_NAME@_LIBRARY
            NAMES @PROJECT_NAME@
            PATHS "${@PROJECT_NAME@_DIR}/../../../@CATKIN_GLOBAL_LIB_DESTINATION@/funky/path/to/foo"
            NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

if(@PROJECT_NAME@_LIBRARY)
  # Multiple CMake projects case (i.e. 'catkin build'):
  # - The target has already been built when its dependencies require it
  # - Specify full path to found library
  list(APPEND @PROJECT_NAME@_LIBRARIES ${@PROJECT_NAME@_LIBRARY})
else()
  # Single CMake project case (i.e. 'catkin_make'):
  # - The target has not been built when its dependencies require it
  # - Specify target name only
  list(APPEND @PROJECT_NAME@_LIBRARIES @PROJECT_NAME@)
endif()
```

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One strategy would be to calculate the relative path to the library on installation and then add it explicitly to the `${crossing_detector_LIBRARIES}` variable using a CMake extra's file. The extra's file would look something like this:

```
# generated from the cmake/crossing_detector-extras.cmake.in file

# Calculate the path to the library
find_library(crossing_detector_wrapper_cpp_library NAMES crossing_detector_wrapper_cpp PATHS "${crossing_detector_DIR}/../../../@CATKIN_GLOBAL_LIB_DESTINATION@/" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

# I think this next part will work, but it is optional.
# If you don't include it then dependent packages
# will need to use the crossing_detector_wrapper_cpp_library explicitly.
list(APPEND crossing_detector_LIBRARIES ${crossing_detector_wrapper_cpp_library})
```

So you'd use `find_library` so that it handles the library prefix and suffix correctly, but if you messed with the library name (it looks like you did) then you may need to do something slightly different, see the `find_library` docs:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html

Additionally you'll need to do this in your CMakeLists.txt to get that file expanded and installed into the devel space and install space:

```
catkin_package(...
CFG_EXTRAS crossing_detector-extras.cmake
...)
```

Also, I *think* you can safely extend the `crossing_detector_LIBRARIES` variable at this point, maybe @Dirk Thomas can chime in on that. However, if not you will need to explicitly use the `crossing_detector_wrapper_cpp_library` variable in downstream packages after calling `find_package(... crossing_detector ...)`. Something like this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS crossing_detector ...)

add_executable(foo ...)
target_link_libraries(foo ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${crossing_detector_wrapper_cpp_library})
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1